# Topological Group Structure on a Subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I have been pondering over this question for quite a long time. Please help.
Is it possible to define some group operation on $[a,b]$ (with the usual topology inherited from $\mathbb R$) so that it becomes a topological group?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The points $a,b$ are "special" in $[a,b]$: They possess connected open neighbourhoods that remain connected after removal of the point. But if $[a,b]$ were a group, then "multiplication" with a suitable element transports $a$ to $\frac{a+b}2$, say, which is not special. This can't happen. (In other words: A topological group looks "the same" around each point)

Answer (score 8):

No. Every continuous map $f$ from $[a,b]$ to itself has a fixed point, where $f(x) = x$. This even holds for all spaces $[a,b]^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by Brouwer's theorem, although the $n=1$ case is easy to see (consider $f(x) - x$ on $[a,b]$ and apply the intermediate value theorem between $a$ and $b$).

And no non-trivial  topological group has this property: for every $a \neq e$, the map $f(x) = x \ast a$ has no fixed points.

Comment: also a nice method!